# Design pattern for configurable factory sought

Tags: design-patterns, configuration-management

Apologies for the title, I'm sure there is some well-known phrase for it but I don't know it. I have a solution for a problem, but I'm not satisfied with and am seeking inputs to help me improve it.

**Problem domain**

I'm working with an SDK for a third party database. To use the SDK I need to instantiate a "Loader" and pass it a configuration object "LoaderConfiguration". This loader can then do certain actions "start_load" "cancel_load" "load_status" etc.

The arguments going into the configuration vary in specificity e.g. "endpoint dns name, RequestAuthenticator at the generic end but down to "load_source_location" or "load_id" at the more specific.

My application supports both starting loads as well as cancelling or checking status of existing loads. In my application I work with a list of "jobs" which might be in states requiring either the former or the latter.  Every time I process a record I need to therefore instantiate a "Loader" with the appropriate settings.

**Currently working solution**

I designed a LoaderFactory which I pass to my application. The loader factory can create an instance of Loader in the desired state (which differs based on whether I'm starting a new load or interacting with an existing one).

Now because some things are generic e.g. the DNS name of the endpoint but others are very specific e.g. the id of a unique load I want something that is able to fill the generic with sensible defaults (from environment variables) and leaves the users of the factory to specify specifics at their leisure.

My Factory currently works in a way that when the factory is instantiated you can pass it a LoadConfiguration. In addition every time the factory is used to build a Loader a LoadConfiguration can be supplied.

When the factory is used to build a Loader it unions the config from environment variables, the factories config and the callers config such that the callers config takes precedence over the factories which takes priority over the environments.

**Self-identified shortcomings of solution**

The above works well enough, but I feel like it's not very tidy. Specifically the following problems strike me

- Factories are often shown to be singletons. In my design I can't do this because each factory instance might have a different configuration passed to it
- I've not seen factories that allow input on their create methods before
- The unioning of three different LoadConfigurations is pretty nasty and has to use use introspection
- For my unioning to work I need to allow the LoadConfiguration to have Optional/None parameters which can cause Null exceptions at run-time

Comment: Your first two points (not singleton, accepts extra input) are not a problem at all; factories being independent instances is a more OO way of doing factories, and whether or not a creator method has parameters is a decision about the interface, and depends on the needs of your application (e.g. maybe not all of the information required for construction is available at the same time). This leaves the other two concerns. Assuming you're not going to rehaul the design significantly, ... 1/2

Comment: ... for nulls, you could perhaps allow the input to be optional, but always fill in (or force) the defaults for the LoadConfig. object (so that your unioning code can assume there are no nulls). Not sure what to say about the overall unioning complexity; perhaps extract the unification logic as a separate class (or a set of helper methods), and delegate that job from the factory to that code. Generally speaking, see if you can identify clear-cut, potentially recurring subproblems, and provide pieces of code organized around those subproblems that you can then compose in different ways. 2/2